# How to copy files from USB Flash Disk to ESXi 5 server?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

Hi I am new to ESXi world. I installed ESXi 5.0 server and installed also client version to my desktop. I need to copy a virtual machine 400 GB from USB drive to ESXi server but I could'nt find how to do it from client. I enabled SSH access. I entered the machine but fdisk -l do not work. How can I do it ? There is no virtual machine exists currently I want copy VM to local disk. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your VM is in ovf format you can use the vsphere client to import it into your ESXi using `File->Deploy OVF Template ...` then follow the prompts on the pop up window.

If it's not in OVF format you can upload it to a datastore and then try to Add it to Inventory

In vSphere Client select the Summary Tab for the main server.

On the `Resources->Storage` panel right click on a device and select `Browse datastore`.

You can then use the datastore browser to create a folder

[image: Create a folder]

to upload files to

[image: Uplaod Files]

Select the files to upload and follow the prompts.

Once the files are uploaded you may be able to right click on them and select Add to Inventory.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ESXi has very limited filesystem support.  If I recall correctly, the USB functionality is limited to FAT16.

Attach the drive to another machine and transfer over the network.

Comment: Copying a 4GB image file over the network is a real suck with the lack of management on the upload side. Any hicup and the entire thing fails.